# PHP Contact Form - Image uploading to temp but not attatching to email

Tags: php, image, forms, file, contacts

I was just wondering if anyone could help out with what should be a fairly simple fix (obviously not for me) for a contact form with image upload. The image DOES get uploaded to the temporary folder, but doesn't appear when I receive the email into my account.

I think the form is nearly there, just can't figure out why the image is not attatching to the email when i receive it - guessing the problem is somewhere in the last 10 lines of code.

I would really appreciate if someone could figure what's going wrong.

```
<?php

ini_set("sendmail_from", "darren@mywebsite.co.uk");
ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.myhostingcompany.co.uk");

if($name = filter_var($_POST['name']))
if($address = filter_var($_POST['address']))
if($postcode = filter_var($_POST['postcode']))
if($phone = filter_var($_POST['phone']))
if($email = filter_var($_POST['email']))
if($details = filter_var($_POST['details']))
if($contactby = filter_var($_POST['contactby']))

/* Subject and Email Destinations */
$emailSubject = 'Work Email!';
$webMaster = 'darren@mywebsite.co.uk';

/* Gathering Data Variables */
$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$addressField = $_POST['address'];
$postcodeField = $_POST['postcode'];
$phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$detailsField = $_POST['details'];
$contactbyField = $_POST['contactby'];

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); 
$max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB)  
$upload_path = './uploads/'; 

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; 
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); 

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

if(!is_writable($upload_path))
die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href=
"' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
else
echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed

$body = <<<EOD
Name: $name
Address: $address
Postcode: $postcode
Phone: $phone
Email: $email
Details: $details
Contactby: $contactby
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Contact-type: text/html\r\n";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($temp_file)));
$tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$success = mail($webMaster, $attatchment, $body, $headers, "-fdarren@mywebsite.co.uk");

/* Results rendered as HTML */

$theResults = <<<EOD
SENT SENT SENT
EOD;
echo "$theResults"
?>
```

Comment: Remember to check `$_POST` fields that they don´t contain harmful characters.

Comment: You're headers a wrong, the parameters to the `mail` function are wrong, and you're passing an undefined variable to `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 2):

Your mail headers are wrong, you need to use MIME to define the different content types (The body of the email and the attachment).

I have some code somewhere that I use for emailing uploads, if this isn't answered for you in about 10-20 minutes I'll try and find it for you.

Good luck!

I managed to dig up the code! It's not the cleanest code ever but it gets the job done. There will be a few tweaks you will have to do as this was originally written to email CSV files, but I've commented it all as much as I can for you.

```
//The recipient(s) who will receive this email.
$mail_recipients = 'example@email.com';

//This is the subject line of the email.
$mail_subject .= 'A new CVS has arrived!';

//This is the emails body.
$message .= 'A new CVS file has been generated and sent to you, please find it attached to this email. <br />';

//This is the full path to the file you want to attach.
$full_path = '/example/path/file.csv';

//The file type of the attachment.
$file_type = 'text/csv';

//Create a file handle to open the file.
$file = fopen($full_path,'rb'); 

//Read all of the files contents into a variable.
$data = fread($file, filesize($full_path)); 

//encode and split the contents.
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

//Close the file, we don't need it anymore!
fclose($file); 

//Create a unique boundary
$new_boundary = md5(time());

//This is your basic header information such as who the email is from and the date it was sent.
$mail_header .= 'From: CSV Admin <noreply@website.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'Date: ' . date('r') . "\r\n";

//This part of the header first defines to the email client that it is a multipart message and adds the emails content/body.
$mail_header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $new_boundary . '"' . "\r\n\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format' . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= '--' . $new_boundary . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . "\r\n\r\n";
$mail_header .= $message . "\r\n\r\n";

//This part of the header is for the attachment and includes the contents of the file, the files name and other information.
$mail_header .= '--' . $new_boundary . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'Content-Type: ' . $file_type . '; name="' . $file_name . '"' . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n";
$mail_header .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"' . "\r\n\r\n";
$mail_header .= $data . "\r\n\r\n";

//This is needed to stop any rendering errors by email clients and signifies the end of the emails header.
$mail_header .= '--' . $new_boundary  . '--' . "\r\n";

//This mails out all of the above.
mail($mail_recipients, $mail_subject, '', $mail_header);

//And we should be done!
```

Comment: added my code for you, obviously it will need to be changed to suit your needs to but this is working code. If you need help please let me know =)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did try something similar, but my main problem when I did that was this part:                                                                     {{{$success = mail($webMaster, $attatchment, $body, $headers, "-fdarren@mywebsite.co.uk"); }}}                                                                                                            apparantley I am only allowed 5 subjects in that part. Would you have any tips on how to re-write the $success function to match your code?

Comment: When you are defining the emails body in the header don't define it in the mail() function, leave that blank. Also is it still the same problem as in your OP? when you are using multi-part emails I suggest you try sending it to different email clients such as hotmail, gmail, atmail etc as they will each render the emails differently and sometimes one client will make it more clear what your problem is and helps with debugging.

Comment: Saw you edited your comment and yes you are using mail() wrong. as the attachment and the emails body are in your headers your mail function should look like this: `mail($webMaster, $subject, '', $header);` What is the email address at the end for? is that the senders address? there is more information on the mail() function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have three distinct errors:

1. The headers for multipart email are a bit more complex.
2. The parameters to the `mail` function are incorrect.
3. You’re passing an undefined variable to `file_get_contents`.

```php
$mime_boundary = md5(time());

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$mime_boundary."--\r\n";

$message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--".$mime_boundary."--\r\n";

$message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$message .= "\r\n";
$message .= "$body\r\n";
$message .= "--".$mime_boundary."--\r\n";

$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])));

mail($webMaster, 'email subject text', $message, $headers);
```

SitePoint has an in-depth article on [Advanced email in PHP Article](http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-email-php/) that you may find beneficial.

Comment: @Darren: If you have any problems with this, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. does doing it this way remove the need for a temporary folder. I can't see anywhere I would include it?

Comment: @Darren nope, the temporary folder is still in use, just instead of setting the file to a variable he is accessing it straight from the $_FILES variable.

Comment: @Rawb92 is absolutely right. The file is automatically stored in the temporary folder when you upload it and deleted as soon as the script ends. In this case, we're copying the file from the temporary folder into the message body with `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the guys said your content type is incorrect and you have:

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($temp_file)));
$tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
```

It should be

```
$tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($temp_file)));
```